# Error: firefox gives me “missing ] after element list”

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

What I'm trying to do is to use ajax to get time from another php file.

So the javascript code looks like this:

```
var timeNow = setInterval(
    $.ajax({
        url: "process/time.php",
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#time').text(msg);
        }
    }), 1000);
```

And here's php code it is posted to.

```
<?php echo gmdate('h:i:s A', time() + 8 * 3600);?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) can be called with a Function object as well as a string of code to execute. [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) returns a `jqXHR` object, which is casted to the string `"[object Object]"`. This string is then executed as code, and raises the error.

You want to wrap the `$.ajax` call in a function:

```
var timeNow = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"process/time.php",
        success: function(msg) {$('#time').text(msg);}
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You should also either specify the dataType or make sure that the response includes the correct content-type header: `header("Content-Type: text/plain");`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
   strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest'){

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('server_time'=>gmdate('h:i:s A', time() + 8 * 3600)));
    die;    
}
?>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function polltime(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({ url: "./get_time.php", cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $("#time").replaceWith("<p id=\"time\">"+data.server_time+"</p>");
            polltime();
        }, dataType: "json"});
    }, 1000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    polltime();
});
</script>


<p id="time"><?php echo gmdate('h:i:s A', time() + 8 * 3600);?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeNow = setInterval(
    function() {  // you missed function within setInterval()
    $.ajax({
        url: "process/time.php",
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#time').text(msg);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

A much easier solution would be the following:

```
var timeNow = setInterval(
    function() {
    $("#time").load("process/time.php");
    }, 1000);
```

See the jQuery [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method; it is designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: This is unnecessarily erroneous and even dangerous, since load interprets the retrieved value as HTML instead of text.

Comment: Yes, but the asker has full control over the PHP file and it returns something very simple. Yes, it could be intercepted and used maliciously, but I doubt a simple time app will be hijacked.

Answer (score -2):

```
var timeNow = setInterval(
    $.ajax({
        url: "process/time.php",
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#time').html(msg); //you have to use html instead
        }
    }), 1000);
```

Make a function and put your code on that and call it on `<body onload"function_name();">`

Comment: you are missing `function()` inside `setInterval`